# how to convert datetime to a yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss format in perl?

Tags: perl, datetime

How do I convert datetime to a different format?
This is my date: Tue Feb 11 08:47:59 2014
how to convert to 2014-02-11 08:47:59

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Time::Piece](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time%3a%3aPiece) module has been included with Perl since 2007.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use Time::Piece;

my $input = 'Tue Feb 11 08:47:59 2014';

my $dt = Time::Piece->strptime($input, '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y');

say $dt->strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S');
```

Comment: be aware though, as I had been wrestling with this way to long... that `strptime` and `strftime` are *locale* dependant and case sensitive. My system was running on `nl_NL.UTF-8`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [DateTime](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/DateTime-1.07/lib/DateTime.pm) module.